# Table behavior in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, class, google-chrome, css-tables

I'm creating a simple memory game and for some reason when I add and remove classes in chrome the table cell expands. Can anybody tell me why this is happening?
This is the script I use to add and remove classes on click. And this is the entire fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/stoney265/4XznK/

```
$('td').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked') || $(this).hasClass('completed')) {
        $(this).stopPropagation();
        $(this).preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    tempArr.push($(this).text());
    var len = tempArr.length;
    if (len > 1) {
        if (tempArr[0] === tempArr[1]) {
            alert("Good job!");
            $('.clicked').addClass('completed');
            $('.completed').removeClass('clicked');
            winCounter = winCounter + 1;
        } else {
            alert("Try again!");
            $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
        }
        tempArr.splice(0, 2);
    }
    if (winCounter === countCells / 2) {
        alert('You won!');
    }
    console.log(countCells, winCounter);
});
```

Comment: Try removing the `text-indent` property from your CSS classes.

Comment: @mohkhan that solved it, is there any other way to hide the text until it's clicked?

Comment: set the background color to black, or set the text color to white  http://jsfiddle.net/4XznK/13/

Comment: See, if you print the numbers in the cell, they can be viewed easily in firebug. So the ideal thing would be to have that info in a JS matrix and use the index of the TDs to calculate your win/loss.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 That could work. Could someone post these in an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text-indent` property is causing the issue.

You can achieve the desired effect by changing the background to black or the text color to white

http://jsfiddle.net/4XznK/13/

```
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    /* background black */
    background-color: #000;
}
.clicked {
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    /* background white */
    background-color: #fff;
}
.completed {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```